# GeoServer does not display images of layers in layer preview

Tags: geoserver, java, windows

Problem - no images appear in 'Layer Preview' screens - just the frame.

I have had no previous installation of GeoServer on Windows - so I followed the steps recommended.

First, I installed Java using OpenJDK17

Then installed GeoServer 2.23. The installer looked for, but could not find Jdk-17, so I poined it to C:\Program Files\Eclipse Adoptium\jdk-17.0.6.10-hotspot (the 'Java_Home' directory)

GeoServer seems to be working fine - connected to PostGIS - layers being
accessed and identified.

But, when I do a layer preview on demo layers, my PostGIS layers etc., I get
'empty maps' - no images.

I suspected this is a Java issue so I've reinstalled both  OpenJDK17 and
GeoServer with no improvement.

Observations:
The Windows installer for GeoServer cannot find JDK17 by itself, it has be
shown the path.
JDK 17 is the version of Java that comes up when I run "Java -version' in
the command line.
The Server Status screen does not work - it throws a HTTP ERROR 500 javax.servlet.ServletException:

Comment: Try with Java 11 - Java 17 support is still experimental. Also look in the GeoServer log and see what is shows

Comment: Thank you Ian, I uninstalled Java 17, installed Java 11 from Oracle, and re-installed GeoServer -  and was pleasantly surprised - everything is working as it should.